# Rails 3 Tree Data Structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, menu, tree

I have bees searching for a good solution for Tree Data Structure in Rails 3.
I'm trying to build a Tree menu.
What do you use and what would you recommend?

Comment: checkout this link as well https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set, been using it with no problems so far.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Ancestry](http://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) is an excellent ActiveRecord gem that allows you to define tree structures.

Comment: Hi Simone, I have just tried to use the gem but Im kind off a newbie to ROR. I really don't know how to save my records using the GEM, could you show some examples?

Answer (score 3):

this looks like the chosen gem for the task.

for use examples, go to railscasts [episode about ancestry](http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry)